# FRM 40735: ON-ERROR Trigger Raised Unhandled Exception ORA-06508

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

From $AU_TOP\Forms Folder I have copied TEMPLATE.FMB to a custom folder on my desktop,

From $AU_TOP\Resources Folder I have copied the following:

```
US Folder having Menu Module  MMB and MMX to  D:\Dev_suite_Home1\Forms

APPSTAND.FMB  -- to -- >>> D:\Dev_suite_Home1\Forms

ALL .pll & .plx  -- to -- >>>  D:\Dev_suite_home1\Forms
```

I have also tried to re-copy the files again but no positive results. I still I get the error :

> FRM 40735: ON-ERROR Trigger Raised Unhandled Exception ORA-06508

Please provide me the possible solution.

Also, Is there a way to see the APPCORE procedures's Bodies from
Oracle Forms Developer 10g?

Comment: First thing I'd do is recompile your MMB, PLL and FMB, connecting to the correct database & schema. Then I'd investigate whether the ORA-06508 is on its own, or if it's accompanied by a ORA-04068 as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376440/ora-06508-pl-sql-could-not-find-program-unit-being-called

Comment: Jeffrey Kemp is right recompile all. But I recommend also to remove the on-error trigger, this may hide other errors and give you back the wrong type. If you remove it you may get the real error.

Comment: Please make sure that you use Compile All (Ctrl+Shift+K) on all of your forms files (mmb, pll, fmb). If that is no helping please use the debugger to step into the form to see where it raises the exception that ends up in On-Error trigger.