# ASP.NET - ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded

Tags: asp.net, oracle

This is ASP.NET application and it is using Oracle package which has global const variable. After this package is complied, first ASP.NET request gets this exception: ORA-04068. I read that it is because of this global const variable.

Please let me know if there is a way to avoid this exception on first request (in PROD environment)?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you compile the specification even though there are no changes.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a PL/SQL package, that doesn't just contain executable code but includes global variables as well (constant or modifiable), all database sessions / connections that have used the package before the compile and access it after the compile, will receive the ORA-04068 error.

It doesn't happen to new session. So one approach to avoid it is to refresh all database connections, e.g. by recycling the IIS app pool.