# Strange ORA-06508 error

Tags: oracle10g

While working on one of the production issue I came across one error in oracle.

> ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called

When i checked in the database i can't found any invalid objects using below query.

> select * from user_objects where status <> 'VALID';

Once all the packages are recompiled by me and then tried there was no error. This is occurring in Database from sometime. Did anyone faced any such issues in past.

Can you please help me finding the RCA for this issue.

Comment: What was being executed, and what was the entire error stack? With other errors that could have been from, say, a stateful package being modified - any active session when that happened could error next time they referenced it, but it would still be valid in the dictionary. Without all the information I'm guess though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376440/ora-06508-pl-sql-could-not-find-program-unit-being-called)

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the quick reply. Here one off the procedure in a package is executed from the scheduled job.

Comment: OK, but if a package was recompiled or invalidated (e.g. by a table it references being altered, or something else it uses changing) then an existing session would see this; not quite sure how the scheduler handles sessions though. I guess you can check if the package has state, and try to figure out if anything changed that might have affected it - hopefully changes are controlled in production so you'd have a record of any work being done? It may have happened some time before the failure though.