# ORA-06508 when calling procedure which is on remote db

Tags: oracle, plsql

In our application (ADF), app team is calling a procedure using dblink. In this procedure another procedure is being called which is in a pacakge. It works fine but some times it gives an error

```
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called
```

When I checked in remote db, I found that the status of that object is **VALID**.

When i restart the application server it works again. Every time i need to restart the application server (Weblogic).

I am not able to find what is the main cause of this issue. Why this is happening again and again after some days. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look on `DBA_OBJECTS` on the remote DB and check `CREATED, LAST_DDL_TIME` to see  if the package was updated. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376440/ora-06508-pl-sql-could-not-find-program-unit-being-called) answer.

Comment: Hi Marmite, I have checked there is nothing changed in package and procedure. I have also checked in DBA_OBJECTS, status is VALID, CREATED, LAST_DDL_TIME is same.

Comment: Try to get the full error stack. If you see `ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded` **this** ist the error you should investigate...

Answer (score 0):

I think your trouble became when someone compile one of package in stack. You can try to make hierarchy `select` query in `dba_dependencies` to check it.

About rebooting of server i think that it is because of in code from outside of db-link has a rollback when it calls. Till they don't reset package of states it error will repeat every time after first error. There is two ways to solve it (my opinion):
1. Catch exception with code `ORA-06508`
2. Wrap function/procedure of especial [pragma](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems039.htm)  which allow to ignore check of package states.